# Installation on virtual LVM disks without partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, virtualization, lvm, kvm-virtualization

I am installing an Ubuntu server in a KVM/libvirt vm with the text/console installer.

I intend to hand over two LVM volumes as root and swap to the VM as virtual disks.
They are detected correctly as `vda` and `vdb`, however the installer seems to force me to partition those as disks, which would defeat the flexibility of LVM.

How can I install Ubuntu with formatting the virtual disks directly instead of using partitions, or is this a bad idea?

Motivation:

The whole point is to reduce the complexity by removing an unnecesary level of abstraction from the storage hierarchy.

1. physical drives: `host:/dev/sd{a,b}`
2. paritioning: `host:/dev/sd{a,b}1`
3. sw-raid: `host:/dev/md1`
4. lvm: `host:/dev/vg0/mylv_root`
5. VirtIO Disk `guest:/dev/vda`
6. partitioning: `guest:/dev/vda1`
7. filesystem: `guest:/`

In this layout, when allocation additional space to a single vm I have to go through these steps:

4. `lvresize`
5. `parted`, which is especially ugly
6. `resize2fs`

To reduce allocated space the other way around (which is even more ugly).

For backups (e.g. with `lvcreate --snapshot`), there is an additional step of `kpartex` as explained by psusi.

I want to remove 6. from the equation because I don't see what value this abstraction provides. But it does cost by addition complexity, possible performance impact, and small space waste.

Hacky solution:

Using `kpartx` I was able to move the root filesystem from a "bootstrap partition" (within another temporary logical volume) to the target logical volume and then boot via direct kernel boot.

```
kpartx -a /dev/vg0/mylv_bootstrapper
dd if=/dev/mapper/vg0-mylv_bootstrapper1 of=/dev/vg0/mylv_root bs=4M
e2fsck -f /dev/vg0/mylv_root
# Edit fstab inside /dev/vg0/mylv_root accordingly
resize2fs /dev/vg0/mylv_root
kpartx -d /dev/vg0/mylv_bootstrapper
```

However:

1. This feels oddly hacky.
2. I don't really like the idea of direct kernel boot as I would have to manually update the kernel version of the guest in the host each time the kernel is upgraded.

Comment: It doesn't defeat the purpose of lvm, and a disk must be partitioned in order to be bootable.  You can still recover or backup from outside the vm just fine.

Comment: @psusi how do I mount a partition inside a partitioned LVM from the Host? There is only `/dev/vg0/mylv -> ../dm-1`, no `mylv1`.

Comment: Run `kpartx -a /dev/mapper/vg0-mylv` to detect the partitions and create devices for them.  Of course, only do this when you aren't running the VM.  When done, run `kpartx -d /dev/mapper/vg0-mylv` to deactivate the partitions.

Comment: @psusi Thanks, this works. I am actually able to move the root filesystem from a bootstrap partition (within another temporary logical volume) to the target logical volume and then boot via direct kernel boot. But I must admit this feels somehow wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to partition / format the space regardless if it is LVM or not.

Yes KVM will see the devices as "vda" and "vdb".

In general, although KVM uses raw partitions / LVM, IMO, it is much more reliable to just use a virtual disk. Takes the same space and you can always use LVM on the virtual disk and / or resize the virtual disk.

Comment: I assume by "virtual disk" you mean an disk image in the filesystem of the host. Why do you think that is more relaiable than using a logical volume?

Comment: "virtual disk" is a file that is used by KVM to install (rather then a raw partition). There are several formats from .vdi to qcow . I have used raw disk images and doing so makes it difficult to resize your physical partitions as the virtual machine sees the partition as an entire disk.

Comment: I am not using raw partitions, but LVM logical volumes. The whole point is that I can easily resize them (and thus provide additional storage to a VM from the host when needed).

Comment: It is a fine shade of grey between "LVM" and a "raw partition". Do as you wish, I have already warned you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that there is a trival answer: If the logical volumes are formatted (e.g. `host# mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg0/mylv_root`), then the installer will detect and allow to use them as "parition 1 of the virtual disk". It can then even reformat the partitions.

However Grub will fail to install, direct kernel boot can be used instead.